# Dart RawDatagramSocket server

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets, udp

I came across this code that lets you send messages over LAN and it works fine on other platforms apart from mac os. On mac os, I can broadcast messages fine, but I'm unable to receive messages back. At first I thought it was my debug entitlements, but I've confirmed that the permissions are there

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
    <true/>
    <!-- Enable network access -->
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    
    <!-- Enable outgoing network connections -->
    <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
    <true/>
    
    <!-- Allow incoming network connections (if applicable) -->
    <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
    <true/>
    
    <!-- Specify specific network services and ports if needed -->
    <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
    <dict>
        <key>allowOutgoing</key>
        <array>
            <!-- Allow outgoing traffic on specific ports -->
            <string>1050</string>
        </array>
        <key>ports</key>
        <dict>
            <!-- Allow incoming traffic on specific ports -->
            <key>1050</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This is the RawDatagramSocket impl

```
class LanChatRepository extends ILanChat {
  LanChatRepository();

  static const _port = 1050;
  static final _ia255 = InternetAddress('255.255.255.255');

  RawDatagramSocket? _socket;

  final _controller = StreamController<Chat>.broadcast()..add(Chat.empty);
  Chat _cachedChat = Chat.empty;
  bool hasInit = false;
  Connection _ownConnection = Connection.empty;
  final List<ReceivedMessage> _incompletedFiles = [];

  @override
  Future<void> initialize() async {
    _socket = await RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, _port);
    _socket!.broadcastEnabled = true;

    final ownAddressIdentifier = Random().nextInt(100);
    final ownAddressData = [
      4,
      ...List.generate(10, (index) => ownAddressIdentifier)
    ];

    // Start listening to and reading packets.
    _socket!.listen((RawSocketEvent event) {
      if (event != RawSocketEvent.read) {
        return;
      }

      final datagram = _socket!.receive();
      if (datagram == null) {
        return;
      }

      // Case of: Own address identifier.
      if (datagram.data.first == 4 &&
          listEquals(datagram.data, ownAddressData)) {
        final address = datagram.address.address;
        final nickname = LocalData.instance.prefs.getString('username');
        _ownConnection =
            _ownConnection.copyWith(address: address, username: nickname);
        return;
      }

      final message = ReceivedMessage.fromDatagram(datagram);

      // Case of: heartbeats.
      if (message.data.type.isHeartbeat) {
        var connections = List<Connection>.from(_cachedChat.connections);

        final existingConnection = connections.singleWhere(
            (element) => element.address == message.address,
            orElse: () => Connection.empty);

        if (!existingConnection.isEmpty) {
          connections.remove(existingConnection);
        }

        connections.add(Connection.fromMessage(message));
        _controller
            .add(_cachedChat = _cachedChat.copyWith(connections: connections));

        return;
      }
      // Case of: NOT heartbeat message.
      if (message.data.type.isFile && message.data.size! > 1) {
        print('Received file part of index ${message.data.index}');
        // Case of: MULTI file messages.
        var incompletedMessage = _incompletedFiles.firstWhere(
            (element) =>
                listEquals(element.data.fileName, message.data.fileName),
            orElse: () {
          // Case of: first chop
          _incompletedFiles.add(message);
          return message;
        });

        final incompletedIndex = _incompletedFiles.indexOf(incompletedMessage);

        // Case of: NOT first chop.
        if (message.data.index != 1) {
          var newData = List<int>.from(incompletedMessage.data.data);
          newData.addAll(message.data.data);

          incompletedMessage = incompletedMessage.copyWith(
              data: incompletedMessage.data
                  .copyWith(data: Uint8List.fromList(newData)));

          _incompletedFiles.removeAt(incompletedIndex);
          _incompletedFiles.add(incompletedMessage);

          // Case of: LAST chop.
          if (message.data.index == message.data.size) {
            var messages = List<ReceivedMessage>.from(_cachedChat.messages);
            messages.insert(0, incompletedMessage);
            _incompletedFiles.removeAt(incompletedIndex);
            _controller
                .add(_cachedChat = _cachedChat.copyWith(messages: messages));
          }
        }
        return;
      } else {
        var messages = List<ReceivedMessage>.from(_cachedChat.messages);
        messages.insert(0, message);
        _controller.add(_cachedChat = _cachedChat.copyWith(messages: messages));
      }
    }, onError: (_, __) {
      debugPrint('Error in socket');
    });

    // Send own address identifier to recognise own address.
    _socket!.send(ownAddressData, _ia255, _port);

    // Send initial hearbeat.
    _socket!.send([
      0,
      ..._ownConnection.username == null
          ? []
          : utf8.encode(_ownConnection.username!)
    ], _ia255, _port);

    // Heartbeat every 5 seconds.
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
      _socket!.send([
        0,
        ..._ownConnection.username == null
            ? []
            : utf8.encode(_ownConnection.username!)
      ], _ia255, _port);
    });

    hasInit = true;
  }

  @override
  Stream<Chat> get stream => _controller.stream;

  @override
  Chat get currentChat => _cachedChat;

  @override
  Connection get ownConnection => _ownConnection;

  @override
  void send(MessageData message) async {
    if (_socket == null) {
      throw LanChatException.uninitialized();
    }

    var data = List<int>.from(message.data);

    if (message.type.isText) {
      data.insert(0, MessageType.text.index);
      _socket!.send(data, _ia255, _port);
    } else if (message.type.isFile) {
      var data = <int>[];
      // Add identifier.
      data.add(MessageType.file.index);
      // Add file name length.
      data.add(message.fileName!.length);
      // Add file index and file size.
      data.add(message.index!);
      data.add(message.size!);
      // Add file name.
      data.addAll(message.fileName!);
      // Add the data.
      data.addAll(message.data);

      _socket!.send(data, _ia255, _port);
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() async {
    await _controller.close();
    _socket?.close();
  }
}
```

Please what may be wrong?